# How to know the date time format used to convert a string to DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I am converting a string to datetime using DateTime.TryParse in C#. Can somebody tell me, how to know which format C# compiler used to convert the string to valid DateTime. I want to know the datetime format used.

Thanks,
Ashwani

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses [DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.currentinfo.aspx) which contains the different formats.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it will be from regional and language settings of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably infer it in some cases from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`.
But I don't think it's possible to be certain which one it was since multiple formats might be valid in one culture.

If you want to be sure, try using `TryParseExact` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using DateTime.TryParse(string s,out DateTime result), the output format depends on your machine's CultureInfo.